# How can I run all the methods in a python file, and return whether any of the methods returns true?

Tags: python

How can I run all the methods in a python file, and return whether any of the methods return true?

What I'm trying is something like below:

```
def rule1(content):
    if content has a value1:
        return true
    return false

def rule2(content):
    if content has a value2:
        return true
    return false

...

def main(content):
    return rule1(content) or rule2(content) or ... or ruleN(content)  #The code line that I don't like
```

And this wll be imported to another python file, and called like:

```
import rules.py

...

def foo():
    ...
    if(rules.main(content)):
        some action
```

The rules will be added continually, so the line in the main method doesn't look that good.

Can I make the main method that doesn't have to be changed afterwards even if a new rule is added?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work. Just use inspect to get all the functions in the current module who's name starts with `rule`, then call those functions.

```
import sys
import inspect


# All your functions...


def main(content):
    for name, ref in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]):
        if callable(ref) and name.startswith("rule") and ref(content):
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to organize all your rules together. This can be done by putting them into a list (manual updating, probably not wanted), tagging them (you could use a decorator to tag them), naming them the same way (all start with "rule"), or placing them in a class. I think using a class is the most straight forward way.

```
class rules:
   def rule1(self,content):
      ...
   def rule2(self,content):
      ...

def main(content):
    r = rules()
    return all(getattr(r,m)(content) for m in dir(r) if not m.startswith('_'))
```

If you don't want the "self", then use @staticmethod.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a really silly hack but you could move all your rule functions inside the scope of your main function then loop through the `dict` returned by `locals` builtin to call each function.

```
def main(content):
    def rule1(content):
        return content == 1

    def rule2(content):
        return content == 2

    funcs = [loc for _, loc in locals().items() if type(loc)==type(rule1)]
    return any([func(content) for func in funcs])

print(main(1))
print(main(2))
print(main(3))
```

[python tutor link to example](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20main%28content%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20rule1%28content%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20content%20%3D%3D%201%0A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20rule2%28content%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20content%20%3D%3D%202%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20funcs%20%3D%20%5Bloc%20for%20_,%20loc%20in%20locals%28%29.items%28%29%20if%20type%28loc%29%3D%3Dtype%28rule1%29%5D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20any%28%5Bfunc%28content%29%20for%20func%20in%20funcs%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28main%281%29%29%0Aprint%28main%282%29%29%0Aprint%28main%283%29%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=1&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [dir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) to get the list (will include dunder functions). Assuming that you use something like `rule` that is only in your desired functions then the following would work.

Rules.py

```py
def rule1(content):
    if content is not None:
        return True
    return False


def rule2(content):
    if content is not None:
        return True
    return False
```

rule_master.py

```py
import zzMisc.rules


def foo(content=None):
    func_list = dir(zzMisc.rules)

    for func_item in func_list:
        if 'rule' in func_item:
            func_to_run = getattr(zzMisc.rules, func_item)
            print(f'result for {func_item} is --> {func_to_run(content)}')


foo('with content')
foo()
```

Result:

```
result for rule1 is --> True
result for rule2 is --> True
result for rule1 is --> False
result for rule2 is --> False
```

Answer (score 1):

Based solely only on your post description such design can be achieve like this:

```
def rule1(content):
    value = 'a'
    if value in content:
        return True
    return False

def rule2(content):
    value = 'b'
    if value in content:
        return True
    return False

def main(content):
    ret = False
    for fn in globals().values():
        if callable(fn) and fn != main: 
            ret = ret or fn(content)
    return ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert main('ab') == True
    assert main('dc') == False
```

This is not an ideal design because: 1) If you ever needed to add other functions here that are not supposed to be hooker on this **OR** operation you will need to cat that second part of the **IF** verification to a **list** of **not-allowed** functions. 2) Even though wild card imports are supposed to be avoided it can happens sometime and that would break your logic as well.

For a more reliable design i would need to consider *how complex each of this relation checks could become*:

1) IF they will remain like a single small line verification THEN i would try go for a list of lambdas using **map**:

```
def main(content):
    terms = [
        'a',
        'b',
    ]
    return any(map(lambda c, x: x in c, [content], terms))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert main('ab') == True
    assert main('dc') == False
```

2) IF your intention is make this relational comparisons a bit more complex over time but never passing from a **one liners** then we might want to go for a list of lambdas and apply a filter instead.

3) Another way would be grouping this functions as Class methods. The encapsulation would provide more security to try indexing this functions:

```
class RuleFilter(object):

    def rule1(self, content):
        value = 'a'
        if value in content:
            return True
        return False

    def rule2(self, content):
        value = 'b'
        if value in content:
            return True
        return False

    def apply(self, content):
        ret = False
        for attr in dir(self):
            field_obj = getattr(self, attr)
            if hasattr(field_obj, '__func__') and field_obj != self.apply:
                ret = ret or field_obj(content)
        return ret

def main(content):
    return RuleFilter().apply(content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert main('ab') == True
    assert main('dc') == False
```

Passing the content through the **apply** will avoid **tagging** the **__init__** as a bounded method. If you want to pass **content** through the initializer it's fine just remember to extend your **IF** to skip it just like we do for the **apply** method itself.